# How to add instance / type paramter to Family Instance in revit api c#

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am working on a project where I need to add custom parameters under Identity data to element like walls and pipe fittings

I was able to add the Parameters and values to walls but for pipe fitting, I was able to add the parameters but I get an error while adding the values.

My code is as follows

```
ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions edco = null;
edco = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions(param, ParameterType.Text);
edco.Visible = true;
var definition = uiApp.Application.OpenSharedParameterFile().Groups.Create("Custom Parameters").Definitions.Create(edco);
uiApp.Application.SharedParametersFilename = originalFile;
var newCategorySet = uiApp.Application.Create.NewCategorySet();
newCategorySet.Insert(doc.Settings.Categories.get_Item(builtInCategory));
binding = uiApp.Application.Create.NewTypeBinding(newCategorySet);
doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(definition, binding, builtinGroup);
if (!double.IsNaN((double)value))
    ele.LookupParameter(param).Set((double)value);//here I get an error 
    //since ele.LookupParameter(param) returned null for pipe fitting
```

Is it because pipe fitting is a FamilyInstance

Is there some other method to add custom properties to Family Instance

Please guide me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to commit the transaction, so the shared parameter really gets added and bound to the category, before starting to populate it and add values, cf. the [need to regenerate](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.33).